# Azure DevOps Container Job with Multiple Repositories

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline where I checkout multiple repos
I execute jobs inside containers but only the main repo is available inside the container. How can I make sure all repos are mounted?

```
jobs:
  - job: Job1
    container: mycontainer:latest
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: repo2
        path: repo2
```

the main repo is available inside the docker under $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(Build.Repository.Name)
repo 2 is only checked out at the host agent but not available in the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what is the problem
When using path, the repo is being checked out to the WORK directory and not the sources directory. This does not get mounted to the container
So I removed the path argument, and now all the repos are available under $(Build.SourcesDirectory)